# Is there any way by which I can select only "JPG", "PNG" and "JPEG" images through UIImagePIcker

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

While using `self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [(kUTTypeImage as String)]` through `UIImagePicker` I am able to select all types of images but my requirement is select only `JPG, JPEG and PNG` type images through photo library and `GIF` and `HEIC`(live photos) are not allowed.

So, Is there any way by which I can prevent selecting **GIFs** and **HEIC** type photo while `imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary`

Code:

```
imagePicker.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: StringConstants.Actions.Camera, style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            CheckPermissions.checkPermission(permissionFor: .Camera,vc:self) { (success) in
                if success {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
                        if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
                            self.view.endEditing(true)
                            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                            self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
                            self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
                            self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.showAlert(withTitle: kEmptyString, message: StringConstants.AlertMessage.cameraAlertMessage, andOkAction: nil )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: StringConstants.Actions.PhotoLibrary, style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            CheckPermissions.checkPermission(permissionFor: .PhotoLibrary,vc: self) { (success) in
                if success {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
                        self.view.endEditing(true)
                        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                        self.imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                        self.imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
                        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }

        }))
```

Comment: Specify the required [media types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mobilecoreservices/uttype/uti_image_content_types) via the `mediaTypes` property

Comment: You can check the image extension after selection by user. If is is not the desired image then you can show alert to user.

Comment: @Mahendra Checking image extension after selection is something like a workaround of this. By setting **mediatypes** to **kUTTypeJPEG** getting below error : `terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: you can check using `let assetPath = info[.imageURL] as! NSURL` and `if assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("JPG") { // your code }`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya you are right but using this way user will get confused that he/she can able to select **GIFS** and **HEIC** images but not able to submit. So What I actually want is an `imagepicker.photolibrary` with only **JPG**, **JPEG** and **PNG** type of image selection.

Comment: @DhavalKansara have you able to find any solution for the crash issue? : terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0

Answer (score 1):

Simply No. There is no way to give input of specific formate to `UIImagePicker` and get the result of only that formate.

`UIImagePicker` only accepts `kUTTypeMovie` and `kUTTypeImage` as a `mediaType`. What you can do is check the image/file extension after picking any image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the identifiers of the only formats required.

Steps to fix this

1. import MobileCoreServices
2. Take a variable of ImagePickerController, lets say

   ```
   let picker = UIImagePickerController()
   ```
3. Specify Media Type as follows

   ```
   picker.mediaTypes = [(kUTTypePNG as String), (kUTTypeJPEG as String), (kUTTypeImage as String)] // This is an array - you can add other format Strings as well
   ```

To cross verify, you will see that videos/GIFs will not be shown to the app user if not mentioned as media type.

Comment: Hi @Komal, 
(kUTTypeImage as String) shows Images which also include .gif files as well. And if I remove kUTTypeImage from the filter, the app crashes with error "'No available types for source 0'". Is there any other way to filter gif and other animated files?

Answer (score -1):

You can specify selected media types in picker View Like this:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [(kUTTypePNG as String)]
```

Comment: Not working - error is: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0'
***`

Comment: Hi @Haya, (kUTTypeImage as String) shows Images which also include .gif files as well. And if I remove kUTTypeImage from the filter, the app crashes with error "'No available types for source 0'". Is there any other way to filter gif and other animated files?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0' ***